# How to recreate/reinit/restart hilt components in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, dagger-hilt

I'm working on an app that allows you to change the language locally.

To make this work without having to restart the app, I'm using the ContextWrapper on the BaseActivity, where I assign the language to the context:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context{ 
     super.attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper(newBase.setAppLocale(Session.getLanguage())))
}
```

To change the language, I have used both the setLocale legacy and the ApplicationDelegate:

**Legacy**

```
fun setLocale(lang: String) {
     val myLocale = Locale(lang.toString())
     Locale.setDefault(myLocale)
     val res = resources
     val dm = res.displayMetrics
     val conf = res.configuration
     conf.locale = myLocale
     res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)
}
```

**New API SDK 33**

```
val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(it)
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
```

They both do pretty much the same thing. The 2nd is more efficient since it recreates the layouts itself.

The problem is that I am using an architecture with ViewModels that implement a RESOURCES Wrapper to get certain types of resources inside the ViewModel without having leaked a context. There is no mistake on the part of the team in using something wrong.

The wrapper is as follows:

```
class ResourceManager(val context: Context) {

     fun getColor(@ColorRes resId: Int): Int = ContextCompat.getColor(getContextWrapped(), resId)

     fun getString(@StringRes resId: Int): String = getContextWrapped().getString(resId)

     fun getDrawable(@DrawableRes resId: Int): Drawable? = getContextWrapped().getDrawable(resId)

     private fun getContextWrapped(): Context {
         return ContextWrapper(context.setAppLocale(Session.getLanguage()))
     }
}
```

What is the real problem?
The problem is that this ResourceManager uses a CONTEXT that when changing the language, this CONTEXT remains with the previous LANGUAGE resource. That is, if the app starts in English and I change it to Italian, the ResourceManager will stay in English.

The solution I found is to Restart HILT as I did with Dagger before, which generated a new component and cleaned the old one. But, with HILT, I don't know how this can be achieved. How can I override singleton resources and create new ones.